# Is there a way to force sub classes to declare an enum and reference it from a super class in an abstract way?

Tags: java, inheritance, enums, abstract

I have two classes `Apple` and `Lemon` that I want to program in a game. A lot of functionality is shared between the two classes such as `draw(Graphics g)` and `setColor(Color color)`.

```
public class Apple {
    public enum Color {
        Red, Green;
    }

    private Color color;
    private Sprite[] sprites;

    public Apple() {
        color = Color.Red;
        sprites = loadSprites("apple.png"); // [0]=redSprite, [1]=greenSprite
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        sprite[color.ordinal()].draw(g);
    }
}

public class Lemon {
    public enum Color {
        Yellow, Green;
    }

    private Color color;
    private Sprite[] sprites;

    public Lemon() {
        color = Color.Yellow;
        sprites = loadSprites("lemon.png"); // [0]=yellowSprite, [1]=greenSprite
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        sprite[color.ordinal()].draw(g);
    }
}
```

Since both are a `Fruit` and share similar functionality, I create an `abstract` super class for both to extend and force as much work as possible into the super class.

```
public abstract class Fruit {
    private Sprite[] sprites;
    private Color color;

    protected Fruit(String filepath, Color colorDefault) {
        sprites = loadSprites(filepath);
        color = colorDefault;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        sprites[color.ordinal()].draw(g);
    }
}

public class Apple {
    public enum Color {
        Red, Green;
    }

    public Apple() {
        super("apple.png", Color.Red);
    }
}

public class Lemon {
    public enum Color {
        Yellow, Green;
    }

    public Lemon() {
        super("lemon.png", Color.Yellow);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't quite work due to there being 2 separate Color enums. I can create a shared `Color` enum, but that would cause both cases to allow invalid colors to be passed in and impossible with certain sub class orderings (i.e. if green was both 1st in apple and 2nd in lemon).

```
public enum Color { // this seems hacky
    Green(2), // Valid for both
    Red(1), // Only valid for apple
    yellow(1); // Only valid for lemon

    private int position;

    public Color(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    @Override
    public int ordinal() {
        return position;
    }
}
```

I tried having them share a similar interface, but that still allows them to pass in each other's invalid colors.

Ideally I would like the sub classes themselves to declare the enum values that are valid and force them to declare a `Color` enum. Setting the enum to `abstract` seems like it should work, but doesn't seem to be allowed in java.

```
public abstract class Fruit {
    private Sprite[] sprites;
    private Color color;

    public abstract enum Color; // not allowed

    protected Fruit(String filepath, Color colorDefault) {
        sprites = loadSprites(filepath);
        color = colorDefault;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to create and set these objects like so, while keeping the setters in the super class.

```
Apple apple = new Apple();
apple.setColor(Apple.Color.Green);

Lemon lemon = new Lemon();
lemon.setColor(Lemon.Color.Yellow);
```

Is there any way to do this, or am I forced to rewrite the `setColor(Color color)` method and remember to add the `Color` enum in all of my `Fruit` sub classes?

**tl;dr**
I want to move functions with a class specific enum parameter into a super class and force the sub class to define the enum. Is this possible to achieve in Java or am I forced to remember to do so myself in all of the sub classes?

Comment: `Apple` and `Lemon` shouldn't really be separate classes. While to a human they're different, they're actually just instances of `DrawableObject` or `Sprite` or whatever you want to call it.

Comment: An `enum` cannot be `abstract` - you can see it as a special kind of concrete class for which each element is an instance of that class. What you could do is have an interface `Color` which is implemented by your `enum` - and you can define the contract you wish to have for a `Color` in this interface. If you cannot extract such an interface from your `Color` enum, that means you don't have an IS-A relationship between your enums and a `Color` entity shared by both `Apple` and `Lemon`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics can be your friend in cases like this:

```
public static class Fruit<C extends Enum<C>> {
    protected C color;

    public void setColor(C color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

}

public static class Apple extends Fruit<Apple.Color> {
    public enum Color {
        Red, Green;
    }

    public Apple() {
        setColor(Color.Red);
    }

}

public static class Lemon extends Fruit<Lemon.Color>{
    public enum Color {
        Yellow, Green;
    }

    public Lemon() {
        setColor(Color.Yellow);
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that using this pattern there is no relationship whatsoever between Apple.Color and Lemon.Color (`Apple.Color.Green` does not equal `Lemon.Color.Green`)

Comment: @BorisvanKatwijk - Correct - see [Per Huss's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46784380/823393) for a good way to connect them (use an `interface`).

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using generics. In order to guarantee that fruits only have a color that is valid for that fruit, I would suggest introducing a `FruitColor` interface (currently only an empty marker interface). When declaring the type variable `C` you can put a constraint that it should be both a `FruitColor` and an `Enum`. Your enum declarations should also implement `FruitColor`. Code sample below:

```
interface FruitColor {}

abstract class Fruit<C extends Enum<C> & FruitColor> {
    private Sprite[] sprites;
    private C color;

    protected Fruit(String filepath, C colorDefault) {
        sprites = loadSprites(filepath);
        color = colorDefault;
    }

    public void setColor(C color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        sprites[color.ordinal()].draw(g);
    }
}

class Apple extends Fruit<Apple.Color> {
    public enum Color implements FruitColor { RED, GREEN }

    public Apple() {
        super("apple.png", Color.RED);
    }
}

class Lemon extends Fruit<Lemon.Color> {
    public enum Color implements FruitColor { YELLOW, GREEN }

    public Lemon() {
        super("lemon.png", Color.YELLOW);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't quite see the reasoning behind adding the extra `FruitColor` layer of abstraction. The `Color` is already limited to the class type, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the fact that you should not store non-shared (since you mentioned that some colors are not eligible for some fruits) options inside your abstract class, since it violates the idea of inheritance.

For this reason, you either stay with that, and let your lemons be red and apples yellow, or you create separate Enums for each class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict the colors (or, more generally, arguments) that a class can be created with, you can provide factory methods like

```
public class Apple extends Fruit {

    private Apple(String filepath, Color color) {
        super("apple.png", Color.Red);
    }

    public static Apple redApple(String filepath) {
        return new Apple(filepath, Color.red);
    }

    public static Apple greenApple(String filepath) {
        return new Apple(filepath, Color.red);
    }

}
```

This prevents you from calling the method with any other color. If you want a more flexible, runtime check, you can create a general factory method with a check:

```
public class Apple extends Fruit{

    private Apple(String filepath, Color color) {
        super("apple.png", Color.Red);
    }

    public static Apple create(String filepath, Color color) {
        throwIfNotGreenOrRed(color);
        return new Apple(filepath, Color.red);
    }

}
```

I advice not to provide setters since immutable code is much easier to work with. If you still want those, the settings should execute the same `throwIfNotGreenOrRed` validation.

Comment: This is a decent solution, but it requires either making a factory method for every color (which would be huge pain if the color types were in the thousands) or having a run time check (which, in a game, isn't desirable).

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you use an Enum. The [Enum Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) states

> You should use enum types any time you need to represent a fixed set
>   of constants. That includes natural enum types such as the planets in
>   our solar system and data sets where you know all possible values at
>   compile time—for example, the choices on a menu, command line flags,
>   and so on.

So if you want to use an Enum in this scenario, make a public shared Enum containing all colors and let your Fruit instances implement a getAllowedColors() method.

```
public enum Color {
    Red, Green, Yellow, Purple, Blue
}


public abstract class Fruit {
    public abstract Set<Color> getAllowedColors();

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        if(!getAllowedColors().contains(color))
            throw new RuntimeException("Color not allowed: "+color);
        this.color = color;
    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a great alternative. The `contains` method is O(n) so if the `Color` enum comprised of a million colors, then this would take way too long to fit inside of a game loop. The best approach for this method would then require keeping a `HashMap` of the colors for O(1) searching, but then it would have O(n) memory usage.

Comment: Not to mention this only catches the error at run time which isn't desirable for a game. My hope was to have a constant time solution that gets caught at compile time, otherwise it would be way better to just hard-code the enum and setter in each of the sub classes since the payoff would be a constant time solution.

Comment: The complexity of `contains` depends solely on the implementation of the collection. HashSet is O(1) in average case, TreeSet is O(log n) guaranteed, EnumSet (which seems like a good choice here) is O(1) guaranteed.